# C# EM_CHARFROMPOS how to cast a point to Intptr?

Tags: c#, winapi, win32com

After I receive the Caret (x,y) position using `GetCaretPos` I want to `SendMessage()` of `EM_CHARFROMPOS`.
The problem is that the `lParam` should be of type `IntPtr`, and the result of `GetCaretPos` is a point.
How do I cast the point to an IntPtr correctly?

Comment: You need a pointer to unmanaged memory.  So use : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The return value of `GetCaretPos` is a [POINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd162805(v=vs.85)). That's binary compatible with a [POINTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd162807(v=vs.85)), so you can pass a pointer to it unmodified, if you are targeting a Rich Edit control. For a standard Edit control, you're going to have to truncate the `x` and `y` fields to 16-bit unsigned values, and binary OR them together into a 32-bit value. You can pass a zero-extended value of pointer size as the `lParam` when targeting a standard Edit control.

Comment: How do I do that? @IInspectable

Comment: That generally involves to stop being a managed-only developer. Apart from that it seems irrational to avoid UI Automation for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need it for google chorme, which doesn't support UI Automation. @IInspectable

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't use native Windows controls either, so that's not going to work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code must be [different if you target a Rich edit control vs an Edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-charfrompos), but you can get inspiration from .NET's code (and you can define multiple versions of SendMessage that suit your needs):

For a text box:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,1754

```
...
var pt = (IntPtr)MAKELONG(pt.X, pt.Y);
SendMessage(handle, EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, pt);
...
public static int MAKELONG(int low, int high) {
  return (high << 16) | (low & 0xffff);
}

[DllImport("user32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

For a rich text box:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,2323

```
...
var pt = new POINT(pt.X, pt.Y);
SendMessage(handle, EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, pt);
...

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class POINT
{
  public int x;
  public int y;
}

[DllImport("user32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, POINT lParam);
```